# Div wont float to the left in the same line

Tags: html, text, floating

I am making a footer with three elements, an h3 and two divs, all elements are floated to the right with a margin percentage.

Problem is the third element(div2) goes bellow the first div instead of floating to the left.

Here is my code, I am aware inline styling is not good idea.

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%; height:70px; position:relative; float:left; padding:2%;">
  <h3 style="float:left; position:relative; margin-right:15%; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); ">Contact our experts</h3>
  <div class="telcontainer" style="margin-right:15%; width:auto; height:32px; position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); overflow:hidden; ">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/icon-experts-call?$GN1201$" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:relative; float:left;">
    <h3 style="position:relative; float:left; margin-left:1%;">694003903</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mailcontainer" style=" width:auto; height:32px; position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); overflow:hidden; ">
    <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/icon-experts-call?$GN1201$" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:relative; float:left;">
    <h3 style="position:relative; float:left; margin-left:1%;">Mail Us</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align items in a row or column, try using `display: flex`. It will save a lot of hassle
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%; padding:2%; display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column">
  <h3 style="float:left;">Contact our experts</h3>
  <div class="telcontainer" style="width:auto; position:relative; display: flex">
       <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/icon-experts-call?$GN1201$" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:relative; float:left;">
       <h3>694003903</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="mailcontainer" style=" width:auto; position:relative; display: flex">
       <img src="https://images.petsmartassets.com/is/image/PetSmart/icon-experts-call?$GN1201$" style="width:32px; height:32px; position:relative;">
       <h3>Mail Us</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This looks easy, I will take a look into it.

Comment: Now how could I do to verttically align the two divs?

Comment: The `694003903` and `Mail Us` divs?

Comment: Yes, I vertically centered the "contact us" with top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); but it is ot workinf for both divs.

Comment: Not like that sorry, I want all three elements vertically centered in the same line, same line as "contact us". Thanks for your help, I am a newbie

Comment: Please check now. No problem at all, anytime. But don't forget to go through the edit history to see what changes I made and learn `flex` it will get super handy and will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You have position:reltive instead of position:rel**a**tive. Does this change anything if you correct it?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but it didn't change anything :(